# js file not being rendered in ejs file

Tags: ejs

I am using ejs independently with piece of html. All the things being rendered from API call & I am templating everything with the help of ejs. There is piece of html for slidebar & using the jquery it's working statically. But when I include that piece of code in the ejs file to make it dynamic, it no longer works.

I am confused. Is there any way to implement it. I want to make whole slidebar content dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to post some code that demonstrates what you've tried and describing what goes wrong.

Comment: thanks skirtle for the reply. You can assume any type of slider code consisting static html of images + jquery. when I made this static content dynamic using ejs its not working.

Comment: Plugin Name: MixItUp & html - <div class="trabalhos-categorias"> <ul id="filters" class="clearfix"> <li><span class="filter" data-filter=".clássico">Clássico</span></li> </ul><div class="trabalhos-secao"> <div class="col s12 m6 l3 secao clássico" data-cat="clássico"><a href="single-portfolio.html"> <img class="image" src="assets/uploads/Vilma-Ribeiro.jpg"> <div class="overlay"><div class="text"> <p><span class="mais"></span></p> Vilma Ribeiro </div> </div></a> </div> </div></div>. js - new EJS({url: 'partials/home.ejs'}).update();